# How to create a dropdown using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, frontend, bootstrap-5

I was creating a dropdown at 'Menubar'. I am using Bootstrap 5.1 to do that. This is an 'ASP.NET Core 6 MVC' project. It'ss also a partial view. The exact code is as following:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown show">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link text-dark" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item">Categories</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">Media Types</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

But whenever I click on this link the dropdown doesn't toggle. If someone can point out the problem that would be very helpful. The reference video is attached [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQNY3quGbDk&list=PL4LFuHwItvKZ6Mz5W5wzD9uo3w6tNChhX&index=7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer are all wrong. I have watched your video, and the reason behine is your code is using bootstrap-4, instead of bootstrap-5.

I have tested your code with bootstrap-4 starter template, and now it works.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link text-dark" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item">Categories</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Media Types</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the starter template by [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/).

If you sure your whole ASP.NET Core MVC Bootstrap's version is 5.1, your code won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here:

**Before**

```
<a class="dropdown-item">>Categories</a>
```

**After**

```
<a class="dropdown-item">Categories</a>
```

**Update**

Adding to the typo you had, like [@seantsang94121](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17681630/seantsang94121) said the other problem here is that you are using this code in bootstrap 5 and it only works in bootstrap 4 as his example shown on his answer -> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70508993/17209963)

Answer (score -1):

you need those:

```
<head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 is already integrated with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC projects.